# Formula of n-th member of combined arithmetic and geometric progression

Tags: math

I have a progression of format (b + 1) * 2.

1, 4, 10, 22, 46, 94, 190...

In code I can do it like:

```
k = 1

for i in range(n):
    k += 1
    k *= 2
```

But doing it with loop is a bit inefficient.  Is there math formula to find it's n-th member?

Comment: There is a formula that will allow you to work out the next member. This is not really about programming though and might be better off on the maths stack exchange site: http://math.stackexchange.com/ (though do check that it is on topic there first).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the starting number is b1, then

```
 2-nd term is 2*b1 + 2
 3-rd term is 4*b1 + 6
 4-th term is 8*b1 + 14
 5-nd term is 16*b1 + 30 ..
 n-th term is 
             b1 * 2^(n-1) + 2^n - 2
```

for your example `b0 = 1`

```
b(n) = 3*2^(n-1) - 2
```